# How do I remove the head off this Giacomini thermostatic radiator valve?

Tags: radiator, valve

How do I remove the head off this Giacomini thermostatic radiator valve?:

[image]
<sup>*Click for larger view*</sup>

I was expecting part of the white bit to twist off easily, to reveal the inner pin on the valve. It looks like there might be some trick to it, e.g  a release mechanism by poking something through the holes. But the bottom white bit is metal and rock solid. Do I need to use wrench to unscrew it? I don't want to remove the valve (gets messy) just the valve head.

My actual problem is that the radiator has simply stopped working, but I'm told it's likely to be the thermostatic valve is broken. By removing the valve head I hope to determine whether this is the case.

Answer (score 3):

In the technical guides for the Giacomini valves, it appears that some of the heads can be removed by unscrewing it past the the open position. Have you tried that? This is assuming that the top part on your model spins.

For other models, it appears the whole head pulls off the valve. An example is shown in this guide: http://www.giacomini.com/export/sites/default/en/download_gallery/certifications/cen_en_215_tech_doc/1257763387429_R452_1-502GB.pdf

In your photo, I can see the tops of the numbers on the valve, but not enough to compare to the various units the manufacturer produces. You might call them for more info at their support line, here:

TECHNICAL MANAGER
eng. SERVILIO GIORIA
tel.: 0322 923 372
servilio.gioria@giacomini.com

```
TECHNICAL DEPARTMENT SECRETARY

Mrs. PAOLA FRATTINI
tel.0322 923 372 - fax 0322 923 255
paola.frattini@giacomini.com
```

Answer (score 2):

You have probably solved this by now. However, for those that haven't here is how to remove the push on Giacomini thermostat.

In the photo you've posted, above, you can see a plastic collar where that thermostat attaches to the valve. This is a locking collar. You can actually see the locking jaws above the collar. Lift this collar and the whole thermostat lifts off the valve.

**Note**: The thermostat may need to be fully open to allow the collar to lift.

Comment: P.S. The thermostat must be fully open or the collar WILL NOT lift.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell 100% as the top of your picture is missing. But it looks like a snap-fit version of the head.
If you go to this link:

http://www.brasswaredealer.co.uk/all-products/radiator-valves-2/giacomini-atlas-head-thermostatic-r452x109.html

or just navigate to the Giacomini Atlas head on

www.brasswaredealer.co.uk

There is a picture of the fitting instructions you can click on - this explains how the head is fitted or removed.

Comment: Link only answers aren't useful if the link goes away. Make sure you answer the question here and the link is only for additional details.